# How can I create a numpy dtype from the string 'long'?

Tags: python, types, numpy

I have a variable that contains the string 'long'. How can I create a numpy dtype object with some type equivalent to long from this string? I have a file with many numbers and the corresponding types. `int`, `float` etc. are no problems, only `long` doesn't work. I don't want to hardcode some replacement `long -> int32` or so in my code.

```
>>> np.dtype('long')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Also: Is there a way to create a variable type from a string in pure python? I mean, I want the inverse of `int.__name__`, which converts the type name into a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, I think you can use `getattr` to get it from the `numpy` module itself:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.dtype('long')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: data type not understood
```

but:

```
>>> getattr(np, 'long')
<type 'long'>
>>> np.dtype(getattr(np, 'long'))
dtype('int64')
>>> np.dtype(getattr(np, 'int'))
dtype('int32')
>>> np.dtype(getattr(np, 'float64'))
dtype('float64')
>>> np.dtype(getattr(np, 'float'))
dtype('float64')
```